# Customizing TensorFlow Serving for BERT or Transformer

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I would like to customize serving_default of BERT or Transformer to make the input as string type and get the prediction as string type. So the model's output should be converted to a sentence according to a dictionary. Are there some reference code or examples for this custom serving? I would appreciate your answers and please share your ideas.

Comment: Could you please refer [custom serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/custom_op) and please have a look at similar issue was described in this [thread](https://github.com/google-research/bert/issues/146), Hope this helps in any way. Thanks